# How to get bulk documents/multi gets based on keys in spring data couchbase

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have been trying to get bulk documents based on a list of id's. But for some reason I don't see a method in CRUD Repo which can give me that data. I was able to locate a method name "FindAll(List)", but this seems to work only on the view named "all", and I don't want to introduce a view for a simple lookup(which primarily should be a functionality of couchbase).

Can someone please let me know what all options I have to achieve my end goal if I dont want to end up using Views or Nickel queries.

Also, why is it not supported by spring data couchbase. Is this something that is not expected?

Answer (score 1):

The `Repository` needs to be able to `findAll()` documents that it is tasked with saving. Problem is, in Couchbase you can save all sorts of documents in the same bucket, so the repository needs a way of isolating only the documents that match its Entity type.

It is done with the requirement of the View for CRUD operations, and for generated N1QL queries by appending a criteria on the `_class` field to the WHERE clause.

When you provide a `List` of keys, the Couchbase repository simply reuses the view you had to configure so that `findAll()` works, which has the additional benefit of ensuring that keys not corresponding to a correct Entity (that is, not indexed by the view) will be ignored.

That said I think it is on the roadmap to remove the view requirement... (But that's up to the Couchbase team. Maybe raise an issue to get a more definitive answer to that).

Spring Data Kay and its support for Reactive Programming will most likely also change the landscape.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/developer/java-2.0/documents-bulk.html), with RxJava you can use effective batching.

Code example

```
bucket.async()
        .query(N1qlQuery.simple("SELECT meta().id as id FROM bucket"))
        .doOnNext(res -> res.info().map(N1qlMetrics::elapsedTime).
         forEach(t -> System.out.println("time elapsed"+t)))
        .flatMap(AsyncN1qlQueryResult::rows)
        .flatMap(row -> 
        bucket.async().
        get(row.value().getString("id")))
        .map(JsonDocument::content).
        toList()
        .toBlocking()
        .single();
```

[RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) is asynchronous and will save additional round-trips and should end up the better performer!

Comment: to add to this answer, you can access the `bucket` through the `CouchbaseTemplate` interface, itself accessible from the `CouchbaseRepository` interface, just in case